# Github webhook PHP script returns "Missing HTTP 'Content-Type' header."

Tags: php, git, github, webhooks

Some information beforehand:

I have 1 servers with 2 domains, one is the live version (live), the other is for testing purposes (redesign).
I'm using GitHub webhooks to automatically update my redesign server with the repository so that when there's multiple people working on the repo, we don't have to manually deploy it every time.

Now, I have found a PHP script **(This is exactly how I use it apart from the secret)** [on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/milo/daed6e958ea534e4eba3) in which the webhook is being parsed returns an error saying that the `Content-Type` header is missing, while when I look in the webhook delivery it clearly has the header.

[image: Header present.]

The error presents itself on line 33 of the PHP script which checks if the `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE` is present by checking

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'])) {
    throw new \Exception("Missing HTTP 'Content-Type' header.");
}
```

To ask an actual question: How can the PHP if throw the exception when the header is clearly present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the name `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE` is wrong. It looks like it has been used as a fix for the bug [Sets HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE but not CONTENT_TYPE](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66606&thanks=6).

Normally `CONTENT_TYPE` property should be used following the [RFC 3875](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875.txt)

I made a simple test to check how it works

1. Created an `index.php` file on my web server

   echo $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'].PHP_EOL;
2. Opened the file using cUrl

   $ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost

The outpus for me is

> application/json

3. `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE` property is not set in my test case.

Comment: This did solve the problem, the `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE` property indeed was not set, it now does pass the check, Thank you.